How air resistance affects projectile distance (roughly)?
Hopefully someone can help.
We have a level conveyor belt that runs at a set speed (about 0.8m/s) but i can change this from 0.2m/s to 1m/s
On the belt are a mixture of different sized plastic particles (all with similar density) ranging from 2mm to 14mm.
The conveyor belt is raised off the ground about 50cm and projects the plastic particles off the end of the belt, so the particles hit the ground.
Assume the plastic particles dont roll or move when they hit the ground, so stay where they hit the ground.
I want to roughly know how air resistance will affect where each size particle lands.
Is it likely to have a negligible affect? Or will we see a large landing spread of plastic particles? And if there is a spread, which size particles roughly will land where?
Then my next question is how much with the speed of the conveyor belt affect the above answer? So for example if we ran the belt at 0.2m/s vs 1m/s

This question could be answered very nicely using a simulation. If you know the underlying physics (the equation for the force of air resistance and gravity), and you know how to program, you could get a pretty quick answer.

At the low speeds in your experiment you can use a simple formula to estimate the drag caused by air resistance:
$$F=-cvA$$
(At high velocities drag is more likely to be proportional to $v^2$ of the object.)
for example see here
Where c is some constant depending on the shape and surface characteristics of your objects and various properties of air, such as density, viscosity etc. $v$ is its velocity and A is some measure of its area, proportional to $w^2$, where $w$ is a linear size measurement which you have specified..
So the force on each object increases as the square of its width i.e. $w^2$, but the acceleration this force cause decreases with the mass of the object which is proportional to $w^3$.
So you should expect the drag caused by air to have less effect on the more massive objects. This will be true whether you use the $v$ or $v^2$ formula.
